# Usage of final option with package animate

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging, animate, draft

I'm currently animating some inline graphics (TikZ) on a beamer presentation with the `animate` package, and have come across some weird behavior.

Since I still have lots of work to do, I set the global option `draft`, and planned to override it on the figure I currently was working on with the `final` option. This is even suggested in the documentation for the `animate` package, with the goal of cutting compiling time while authoring a document with many animations.

The problem is, when I include the `final` option locally, my code won't compile. I get the error:

```
! Argument of \multiframe has an extra }.
```

I have quintuple-checked my syntax. As soon as I remove the `final` option, the code compiles without a hassle - but I have to remove the global `draft` option to see the current figure, and all other figures get compiled as well...

I'd like to see if anyone can reproduce this behavior, so that I may contact the package maintainer with a bug report. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[draft]{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
      \column{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Lorem
          \item ipsum
          \item foo
          \item bar
          \item ...
        \end{itemize}
      \column{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,width=\textwidth,final]
          \multiframe{15}{i=0+1}{%
            \tikz{\path node {This is where I draw my complex figure at timestep \i};}
          }%
        \end{animateinline} 
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might check a sixth time. You missed the mandatory frame rate argument. The example uses here one frame per second.

The example now compiled with the `final` as well as the `draft` option.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[final]{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
      \column{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize} \item Lorem \item ipsum \item foo \item bar \item ... \end{itemize}
      \column{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,width=\textwidth,final]{1}% 1 fps
          \multiframe{15}{i=0+1}{%
            \tikz{\path node {This is where I draw my complex figure at timestep \i};}
          }%
        \end{animateinline} 
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Obvious mistake, wasn't well rested, so 10 more checks probably wouldn't have been enough. Still, I find it somehow mysterious that it the one option worked and the other didn't if my syntax was wrong... but TeX's inner workings are really awkward sometimes.

Comment: @MHaaZ Happens to everybody. :) (My first sentence is obviously a joke.) Interestingly enough, I couldn’t compile your example with `draft` or `final`.